# Unhandled Runtime Error

Tags: dapps, polygon

I am creating an NFT marketplace using the Matic/Polygon Network.I deployed my contract and wrote on my console `npm run dev`. The front end of the dapp works in `localhost:3000`. However I am getting this error.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.5.0)

Call Stack
Logger.makeError
node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib.esm/index.js (185:0)
Logger.throwError
node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib.esm/index.js (194:0)
JsonRpcProvider.eval
node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib.esm/json-rpc-provider.js (357:0)
Generator.throw
<anonymous>
rejected
node_modules/@ethersproject/providers/lib.esm/json-rpc-provider.js (6:41)
```

Is this something wrong with the index.js file? How can I interpret this ? as I am new to blockchain to debug the problem. Additionally, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: We would need to see the code, please update with the piece of code that returns the network being used

Comment: I fixed the issue. I had to change `const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider()` in my index.js file to     `const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3.currentProvider)`. But thank you for the help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.